# how to create trigger to update a column by adding prefix of another column

Tags: mysql, triggers, prefix

I need to update `prefixed_sku` column by prefixing "A|" for every insert or update on column `sku`

- SKU------------prefixed_sku
- Hp3001-------- A|HP3001
- HS1001-------- A|HP3001

I tried reading many articles but I'm not a programmer so could not figure it out on my own. This is for my orders database. Thanks

```
table name: orders
column name: sku
```

Comment: Cleanup wording and add some formatting

Answer (score 0):

Add an after insert and after update trigger to go back and update the prefixed_sku column in the orders table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_order_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON orders
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE orders
    SET prefix_sku=CONCAT('A|',sku)
    WHERE sku=NEW.sku
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_azt_insert
    AFTER INSERT ON azt
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    UPDATE azt
    SET TSKU=CONCAT('A|',sku)
    WHERE sku=NEW.sku
END$$
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I changed it according to my table name (azt) & prefix column(TSKU) it is giving this error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8
----Thanks for your help

Comment: sku & TSKU (  both are on the same same table)